# Pegar lower_bound de um multiset no modo indice 0

Tags: c++

Aqui vai o código:

```
first = mult.lower_bound(c);
        last = mult.upper_bound(c);
        if (first == mult.end())
        {
            printf("%d not found\n", c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d found from %d to %d\n", c, first, last);
        }
```

O problema é que o first e o last são iteradores, eu já tentei first - mult.begin() mas a IDE não aceita :/

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, usei um `distance(mult.begin(), first)` e pro last também :D